# problem with masked input plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, mask

I do not know why after adding new input, [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) does not work on it(new input)?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/yx5wa/1/

```
$('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newDiv = $($(this).closest('.adding').get(0)).clone(true);
    $(this).closest('.adding').find('.add_input').remove()
    newDiv.find('.adda').not(':has(.remove_input)').append('<div class="mediumCell"><a href="" class="remove_input">remove</a></div>')
    newDiv.hide().fadeIn('slow')
    $('.adding:last').after(newDiv);
    $('.adding' + ':last input:checkbox').prop('name', 'checkbox_units[' + size_un + '][]');
    console.log($('.adding:last input:checkbox').prop('name'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there were two issues:

1. The plug-in needs to be applied again to the new input within your click event:

   ```
   newDiv.find('input').mask("9999/99/99");
   ```
2. The `clone` function needs to be called with `withDataAndEvents` set to false:

   ```
   var newDiv = $($(this).closest('.adding').get(0)).clone(false);
   ```

It seems like you were trying to clone the input and then use `.clone(true)` to bring the mask functionality along for the ride (right?). Unfortunately, it looks like this won't work. You can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BSrKs/1/), when I try and clone the input, it looks like references to the original input are still stuck in there, creating some strange behavior.

Comment: how can type date of right to left in input `rtl`(start typed of day and end typed year),(the first typed is the day, the second typed is the month, the third typed is the year => `third typed-year/second typed-month/first typed-day`) and format it is like: `2011/09/05`

Comment: @Jennifer Anthony That's a complex enough question that you should probably open it up as a separate question (that way you can get the best implementation of it)